# Best way to handle a try/catch exception in a do ... while() evaluation?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, do-while

In this scenario:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHandler.fetchEvents();
boolean someBool = true;

do {
    someStuff();
    variables = things;
    otherStuff();
} while (someBool && cursor.moveToNext());
```

There is a possibility that cursor.moveToNext() could throw a number of exceptions, particularly if my database is closed unexpectedly while I am working with the cursor.

What would be the best way to handle any possible exceptions thrown in the while() evaluation?  Currently, the whole thing just crashes.  I'd prefer to avoid that.  The compiler does not like my efforts to add a try/catch directly into the while() eval, and it's ugly as hell.  I'm thinking I need to create a new method that does this:

```
private boolean moveToNext(cursor) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = cursor.moveToNext();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ... error handling ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then change my eval loop to:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHandler.fetchEvents();
boolean someBool = true;

do {
    someStuff();
    variables = things;
    otherStuff();
} while (someBool && moveToNext(cursor));
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?  If so, I'd love to hear them.  Thanks!

Comment: Your proposed solution is exactly what I would recommend.

Comment: I would recommend moving the `return result` into the try or into a finally.  If you use a try / catch, try/catch/finally should be your top scopes, with the business logic in the try block, the error handling in the catch block, and anything that you want to happen regardless of whether or not there is an error in the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

Put the entire block of code in a try / catch block, and that block should capture when you lose your database connection.

Then you need to reinvestigate the entire block to see what makes sense to clean up, and that will give you the contents of the "catch block" of the try / catch.  Once you do that, you'll probably notice further improvements on your real code, which will probably make this example you posted, and the suggestions less relevant as you zero in on what you care about.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on what you want to happen when you encounter an error. When you get the Exception, should you just skip that iteration of the loop and move on to the next one, or simply stop iterating? Or is the whole loop borked, and you need to tell your user that something went wrong?

If you really care about handling each iteration of the loop separately, then your approach will work fine. Or if you want to just detect whether the entire loop encountered an error or not, then you can wrap the whole thing in a try block:

```
try {
   Cursor cursor = dbHandler.fetchEvents();
   boolean someBool = true;

   do {
        someStuff();
        variables = things;
        otherStuff();
   } while (someBool && cursor.moveToNext());
} catch (Exception e) {
  //report to the user that the loop failed
}
```

Comment: The exterior logic (I didn't include it, just so the question was clear) is that if either someBool != true or cursor.moveToNext() != true, this loop is done and nothing else needs to happen.  This whole block is over 300 lines (I didn't write it), but I suppose it might make sense to wrap the call to it in a try/catch as a sort of last ditch effort to prevent a crash.

Comment: @AWT Exceptions aren't just for preventing a crash. They're for reporting an error up the chain, either to the user or to the calling code. The question you need to ask yourself is what information you need to pass up the chain- do you just need to stop the loop? Do you need to report the specific iteration of the loop? Or do you just need to report that the loop encountered an error?

Comment: Good point.  In this case, preventing a crash is my primary concern.  Secondary to that is to terminate this loop cleanly and let the caller know that it is done.  The calling code has logic to handle whether this all evaluates to true or false, I just left most of it out to keep it easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can always move the code in `while()` to the loop body, no big deal

```
while(true)
{

    ...
    if( ! someBool )
        break;
    if( ! cursor.moveNext() )
        break;
}
```

then surround it with whatever code you like.